# bash:How to pass special characters in to command prompt

Tags: bash, unix, special-characters

I need to pass special characters into my bash script, like this

```
./run -r ,.?!:;()[]{}"' text1.txt
```

however I get this:

```
-bash: ;: unrecognized history modifier
```

Is there any way to pass these instead using back slash before all the special characters?

Comment: I had added code blocks to make your question more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass literals either by backslash-escaping them, or by quoting them.

```
./run -r ',.?!:;()[]{}"' text1.txt
```

However, this does not include a single quote; the quotes are processed and removed by the shell. You can get a literal single quote by putting it in double quotes; put the single-quoted string immediately adjacent to the double-quoted single quote;

```
./run -r ',.?!:;()[]{}"'"'" text1.txt
```